# How to disable the Go button on a native keyboard when developing an iphone app using phonegap and jquery mobile?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Ok, I am developing an iphone app in xcode using cordova/phonegap.

For one of my pages I have a basic email form. As Shown below:

```
<form name="emailformbtn" id="emailformbtn" action="" method="post">
To: <input type="email" name="emailvarto" required="required"/>
Message:<textarea cols="40" rows="8" id="emailmessagebtn" name="emailmessage">Email Message here</textarea>
```

On selection of the email field, a native iphone keyboard is displayed. If the user selects the done button, everything works as normal. However if the user selects the 'Go' button on this native keyboard, it redirects the user back to the start of the app. Does anyone know a way to disable the 'Go' button redirect and make it act as the 'Done' button does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try defining a `submit` handler for this `form`

```
var submitHandler = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
};
```